# Android layout inside ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

The row of my `ListView` is made of two `TextView`s:

I have to position the first `TextView` at the leftmost position and the second `TextView` at the rightmost position. How can I achieve this?

(Minimum API support should be at least `2.3 Gingerbread`)

Comment: see this [tuts](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html) and create your own row for textview

Answer (score 0):

Simple make a layout xml file, which will be inflated into each row and in that layout you can use for example `android:gravity="left"` and `android:gravity="right"` for first and second `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement Custom List Adapter and in the Layout add RelativeLayout with two textview one aligning to left with parent and one with right.

Answer (score 0):

See [ListView Customization](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)
and [Custom List adapter](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)

Answer (score 0):

Best practice it is using RelativeLayout for this purpose

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
        >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtViewTitle"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the following markup worked for me:(tested on Android 2.3 device)

For the 1st TextView:

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
```

For the 2nd TextView:

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```